# Software for linux to reboot to USB

Tags: usb, boot, bios

I have and old computer with Wary puppy installed and want to install Linux mint instead. My BIOS does not support booting to USB so I was wondering if there was any software that allows you to reboot into Wary puppy but the software sends you to the USB stick. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Is it old enough to support floppy disks ? Is a cdrom drive installed ? Does the network card support pxe ?

Comment: @Marged I don't have any spare cds/floppys at the moment and it doesn't support pxe.

Comment: What is your bootloader ? Grub ?

Comment: @Marged Yes, But it doesn't seem to recognise my USB stick.

Comment: I tend to suggest you invest the 50 cent and just get a rewritable CD an Monday ... But you could try this: http://serverfault.com/questions/98950/how-do-i-chain-boot-from-grub-to-syslinux

Comment: if Wary puppy uses grub2, you might be to add an entry to the mnt.lst file so that it first boots grub from the hdd but then the entry in the mnt.lst file points to the USB.